# Login problem with Impersonation in Active Directory + Crystal Reports + C# + SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory, crystal-reports

I am developing an application that needs to run Crystal Reports. The database connection strings are dynamic, and the connection is established at runtime. There are multiple databases that can be referenced, so the connection is assigned at runtime.

To access a specific database, access is granted using an Active Directory user. This user has permission to query the database using integrated security, but cannot log in as a normal Windows user. Also, they don't have permission to log in to the client machines running the app. The user running the app doesn't have access to the database.

Through Impersonation, I have managed to make queries to the database. However, I have not been able to make Crystal Reports run as the user with access.

The connection for the Crystal Reports report is assigned before opening it as follows:

```
private void AssignDataSource(string connString)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connString);
    if (csb.IntegratedSecurity)
    {
        report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(csb.DataSource, csb.InitialCatalog, true);
    }
    else
    {
        report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(csb.DataSource, csb.InitialCatalog, csb.UserID, csb.Password);
    }
}
```

However, this way, the credentials of the correct user are not applied. Instead, it tries to apply the credentials of the user running the APP, who does not have access.

The way I intended to overcome this obstacle was to delegate the entire creation of the report to the user with database access by calling the report like this:

```
LibreriaGenerica.Clases.Impersonation.ImpersonationHelper.Impersonate<object>(user, pass, () =>
{
    FormPrevisualizadorReporteGenerico p = new FormPrevisualizadorReporteGenerico(new crReporteDiagnosticoConexion(), BDManager.GetInstanceGICO().GetCadenaConexion());
    p.ShowDialog();
    return null;
});
```

However, since this user does not have permission to log in to the client machine, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'ReportesGenericos, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access denied.'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the database.  Then check log files in the explorer under Management.  Each connection to the database will show a login with the User and Group.  There is something different with User/Group when working and not working.  You may be able to change the permission of the database so it will work with Crystal Reports or fix the issue with Impersonation.

Comment: The user with access to the database does not have permission to log in directly to it using SQL Server Management Studio. They only have permission to delegate queries. I can do it through, for example, Excel, and I can do it through a SQL Connection in C#, but I cannot log in directly as a regular user in the database.

Comment: integrated security will pass the user login credentials to the database.  Is the login window of SSMS set to Windows credentials (integrated security) or SQL Credentials?  If user can access database with Integrated than they have permission with Windows Credentials.

Comment: I'm confused: is the user who runs Crystal Reports not the user you want to authenticate to SQL Server? Then who is?

Comment: Check out sql server logins, they're pretty great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the issue. I can impersonate the entire call to the CR report so that queries are executed with the user who has access to the database, and I have resolved the access problem to the file with the report by loading it beforehand and refreshing it afterward:

```
//--- 
crReporteDiagnosticoConexion cr = new crReporteDiagnosticoConexion();
            cr.Load();
            FormPrevisualizadorReporteGenerico p = null;
           
LibreriaGenerica.Clases.Impersonation.ImpersonationHelper.Impersonate<object>(userName, userPass, () =>
            {
                p = new FormPrevisualizadorReporteGenerico(cr, BDManager.GetInstanceGICO().GetCadenaConexion());
                cr.Refresh();
                return null;
            });
            p.ShowDialog();
//---
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do impersonation in my web apps.

```
    '+++ Impersonation
    Dim currentWindowsIdentity As WindowsIdentity = CType(User.Identity, WindowsIdentity)
    Dim impersonationContext As WindowsImpersonationContext

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentWindowsIdentity.Name) Then

        impersonationContext = currentWindowsIdentity.Impersonate

        'Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here.

        impersonationContext.Undo()

    Else

        'Unknown user. Probably in debugger.
        'Insert your code

    End If
    '---
```

Comment: `currentWindowsIdentity` and `impersonationContext` need `Using` to dispose them properly

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the user running the APP is user A. The user with access to the DB is user B. User A does not have access to the DB, and user B does not have permission to log in to clients (and therefore does not have permissions to execute the App or access client files).

Additionally, user B only has access to the DB through integrated security, i.e., they cannot log in to the DB using a username and password.

I have not had problems performing queries in the following way:

```
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string query, List<SqlParameter> parameters = null, int timeout = 300)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSQLConn())
    {
        if (impersonated)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(StringCrypt.DecryptConnectionStringPassword(connection.ConnectionString));
            return ImpersonationHelper.Impersonate<DataTable>(sb.UserID, sb.Password, () =>
            {
                return ExecuteQuery(query, parameters, timeout);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return ExecuteQuery(query, parameters, timeout);
        }
    }
}

private DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, List<SqlParameter> parameters, int timeout)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSQLConn())
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value));
            }
        }
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = timeout;
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        return dataTable;
    }
}

[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public static T Impersonate<T>(string fullDomainUserName, string password, Func<T> action)
{
    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 8;

    try
    {
        string userName = fullDomainUserName;
        string domain = "";
        if (fullDomainUserName.Contains("\\"))
        {
            userName = fullDomainUserName.Split('\\')[1];
            domain = fullDomainUserName.Split('\\')[0];
        }

        bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle);

        if (false == returnValue)
        {
            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret);
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        }

        using (safeTokenHandle)
        {
            using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
            {
                using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                {
                    T result = action();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error during impersonation: {ex.Message}");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly.

However, I cannot impersonate connections for CR reports.